# Can't intercept request with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to intercept request however this request uses Bearer token in header
[image]

I tried this code but it's not working
[image]

Comment: Try the static response example [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-StaticResponse-object)

Comment: Please add code instead of images where applicable. Also, is there a reason that you are matching on the authorization header as well? Why could you not just match on the url?